# How do I measure the amount of energy consumed by a device?

Tags: power-supply, solar-energy

I am considering installing solar panels to power a shed. The shed will need a lighting, a fan, a heater, and some other appliances. How do I measure how many kilowatt hours of energy is consumed by a specific device over a certain period of time? I want to do this to get an estimate of just how many kilowatt hours of energy the solar panels will need to generate.

Comment: Energy over time is called power. What you need is how many watts the solar panels will need to provide, not how many watt-hours.

Answer (score 1):

For most loads, you can look at the ratings that are marked on them and estimate how many hours per day you will use them. The heater will be more difficult. You need to calculate how much heat is lost given the area of the walls roof and floor. You use the difference in temperature between the outside and the air around the walls ground and roof. You must find the thermal resistance or insulation value for the type of construction, windows etc. You must also calculate the heat gain through areas exposed to the sun. You need climate data for the average outside temperature. You can calculate everything using a spreadsheet or use a program that has a lot of the necessary information pre-loaded. In some countries, such programs are available from the government.

Answer (score 0):

To measure the heater, a device called a "kill a watt" can be plugged in between the heater and the outlet. It can measure your current power usage or your energy usage over a day. Measure on the coldest day to get a better estimate, or leave the door open a small crack to estimate what heat transfer will be like on a significantly colder day.

For the other devices, the specs will tell you the power, and multiplying by time will give you the energy.

Comment: Yes, but on a hot day the heater will use less  energy compared to a cold day.

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks, I've incorporated that into my answer.